# How to customize Xubuntu with remastersys?

Tags: xfce, custom-distributions, remastersys, cairo-dock, xfce-panel

I've been trying to make my own custom xubuntu-based distro. I thought I understood how to import settings and features and repackage using remastersys, but apparently not.
One of the features involves removing the xfce4-panel and replacing it with cairo-dock(with my own theme), but with each ISO it keeps asking me to how I want to configure xfce4-panel and forgets about auto-starting cairo-dock.

Also when I do manually start cairo-dock it doesn’t have the theme i designed selected by default. I made sure I selected my user-name when configuring remastersys, as well as copying over the files/directories from my home directory to `/etc/skel/`. I even later moved my user-space over to `/etc/skel/`, but to no avail. Anybody know how what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the problem you had, and I found the solution.

Your personal menu settings is stored in :

```
~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu
```

and your personal panel settings is stored in :

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml
```

And the system-wide settings are stored in the locations below :

```
/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-applications.menu (menu)
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml (panel)
```

So if you want to reflect your personal customization in system-wide setting for remastering, you just need to type these two commands from the terminal.

```
sudo cp ~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/
sudo cp ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-panel.xml /etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/
```

However, in your setting, this should remove the panel, but I'm not sure about cairo-dock.

Hope this helps to some extent.